# Which one is fundamental to the other between abstract algebra and linear algebra? (soft question)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, self-learning, education

I saw a post online the other day that mentioned how *"linear algebra is one of the most widely developed fields in mathematics in the $21^{st}$ century*" and whether it's true or not, I'm not sure, but it did spark a little bit of interest, and so I was wondering:

is abstract algebra fundamental to linear algebra, or is it the other way around, or are the two independent? I'm asking because I'd like to initiate studies into these areas, but am having a little bit of trouble finding out where to begin. If anyone can advise me that would be greatly appreciated.

Also, I'm aware that vectors come up a lot (**a lot**) in linear algebra, and because of this I was also slightly concerned that a knowledge of multi-variable calculus and its vector spaces is also required. Is it possible for anyone to confirm this?

> Question in short: which area of study is more logical to start with: linear algebra or abstract algebra, and why?

Thank you.

*PS:* It's true, I could've Googled this, but the majority of resources on Google would be objective, and I'm looking for a bit of personal advice, hence I am asking here.

Comment: Linear algebra is a part of abstract algebra.Linear algebra like an algebraic structure it's a group it's a module, it's a ring  it's an algebra.

Comment: Pretty vague question:  most parts of mathematics relate to other parts of mathematics in *some* way.  Formally, I guess, linear algebra belongs to a part of abstract algebra, either module theory or vector space theory.

Comment: For the record, when you get into how vectors arise in multivar calculus, you're also creeping toward a mixture of linear algebra, topology, and analysis.

Comment: Thanks for the input (and the heads up regarding the question, I think I've narrowed it down slightly) with the idea that linear algebra is part of abstract algebra in mind, does that imply that it's a better idea to start with abstract algebra first? (i.e. the basics, etc.) and then moving on to linear algebra? @Randall

Comment: linear algebra is a special case of the abstract theory

Comment: I think it is a horrible idea--as a student--to start with the abstraction and then work backwards.  You need the specific case (linear algebra) FIRST before the abstraction (module theory) so that you UNDERSTAND why the abstraction is done the way it is.  As a young PhD student I got fussed at by my future advisor for trying to understand model categories before knowing what an actual cofibration is in standard homotopy theory.  He was exactly right.  Cart, horse, etc.  Happy studying:  it's all beautiful stuff, take your time.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the input, it makes good sense. @Randall

Comment: I understand the attraction:  if I learn the complete abstraction first then I will know everything before.  It sounds very efficient.  However, it's not, because you have nothing to base the abstraction on, so you have absolutely ZERO intuition behind the material.  This was my situation before I saw the light.

Comment: It can go the other way too.  One of the most powerful and widespread tools in modern abstract algebra is representation theory, wherein one studies abstract algebraic structures by representing elements in the structure with linear operators, thereby converting abstract algebra questions into linear algebra questions. One could argue that abstract algebra is a special case of linear algebra in these situations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's more logical to start with linear algebra (perhaps not *every* aspect in the field, but certainly the fundamentals.)

Understanding how vector spaces and their endomorphism rings work, transformation groups via matrices, and analyses like the Jordan Normal Form, provide vital examples and geometric intuition that can be used in abstract algebra. Understanding fields and vector spaces makes the jump to rings and modules easier, and understanding transformation groups leads you to groups and so on.

It is difficult to learn or make conjectures in an abstract area unless you have a lot of good examples and experience provided by something like linear algebra. I would consider it a bad idea in general to take an abstract algebra course ahead of basic linear algebra and real analysis.

In order to reinforce a foundation for later work with commutative algebra, I would also recommend learning the basics of complex and real analysis. These two things, along with linear algebra, provide an excellent supply of intuition to build upon while learning abstract algebra.

Comment: +1 for having examples to go on.  The best way to understand (especially why converses may be false) is to have a healthy supply.

Comment: I'm almost certainly going to refer back to this answer in the near future, thank you for the insight. :)

Answer (score 3):

It's normal in every university program I've ever seen to do linear algebra first, so if your goal is self study then the overwhelming evidence is linear algebra should come first.

You certainly don't need any vector calculus to begin learning linear algebra either.